# onSend REST API changes do not reflect in the UI

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

We are using the onSend event to perform some REST API requests that may change and update recipients and the draft item body.

However, those changes are not reflected in the UI and when the onSend event is completed while allowing the send event to continue, the draft item is sent without the changes (successfully) made through the REST API.

Can this behaviour be confirmed ? and if so,
is there a way to force the UI to update before completing the onSend event?

We are trying to work around this by sending the item through the REST API as well, but that conflicts with completing the onSend event in the following cases:

- item sent through REST API + onSendEvent.complete(allowEvent : true)
  I believe we get a UI error after OWA tries to send the item
- item sent through REST API + onSendEvent.complete(allowEvent : false)
  Nothing happens, the UI still shows the draft that no longer exists

Might it be the case that the REST API does not cause the UI to be updated, but using the OfficeJs API dóes update the UI ?

Comment: That is correct. If access the Draft via Microsoft Graph, the client has no idea what (if any) changes were made. This is different from `office.js` where any changes you make are made _in_ the Outlook client (and obviously therefore immediately known to the client).

Comment: Either that, or the fact that a dialog opened within the OnSend event blocking the UI was our expectation. 

But the strange thing is, we find, that without a dialog launched from the OnSend event, the REST API dóes seem to update the OWA UI. 
Our problem seems to be solved, even though we use the  REST API. should we find problems we can switch back to `office.js` method calls.
But how is this possible? Does OWA use polling to check for possible updates ? and thus the UI updating before sending is coincidence?

Comment: What Marc said earlier is correct. When you use office.js API to make changes, the changes are made to the message in the client. When OWA proceeds to send, the message is updated on the server and subsequently sent. As to why you seem to see updated UI with a dialog: as you asked, In general, OWA does get update from the server (for example, save a draft in another client, you will see the draft in OWA). So, the UI updated before sending is really a coincidence/timing, and I don't believe you can rely on that as a robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is expected. REST API modifies the copy on the server. During onSend event, the message is still on the client and the message itself is not necessarily updated to the server yet. After the onSend event completes, OWA will then update the message to the server and send. There is no way to force OWA to update from the server during onSend event or before onSend event completes.