# Deterministically setting OfficeJs item mail headers in OnSend

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

How can one be sure that even if an EWS call to set item internet headers succeeds (I.E. a `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` call's result status is not `Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed`), those headers are also present on the officeJs mail item BEFORE completing an onSend event ?

This question relates to:

[onSend REST API changes do not reflect in the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427857/onsend-rest-api-changes-do-not-reflect-in-the-ui)

and

[using ExtendedProperties in the Outlook REST API to set Message item headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552123/using-extendedproperties-in-the-outlook-rest-api-to-set-message-item-headers)

Answer (score -1):

The most straightforward answer for this is the change key.  Any change to any property on an item will result in that item having a new change key.  When you call SendItem/UpdateItem and pass in the change key that you have, IF the item has changed (including message headers), the call will fail due to conflict resolution, assuming that you pass in the NeverOverwrite conflictResolutionMode for UpdateItem (which can also send).  If I recall correctly, SendItem will always fail if the change key has changed.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer. But how does this relate to the onSend event ? We don't get any change key conflicts, the mail item gets sent but the headers are not present when we check the sent mail. Even though the item header call was successful.
In other words, if I can not force the user interface to update the mail item from the server, how will I be able to know when -or better yet, enforce- that the change keys are the same ?

Comment: The following is not a fix, but at least a temporary stopgap:
What we can do for now is prevent the sending of the item if the changeKeys differ. 

It is a stopgap, because we should actually just be able to the onSend complete event sending a mailItem with all performed changes, and not with some (headers) missing. I feel that this has not been properly thought out ór at least pointed out for the OnSend flow completion.

Comment: the stopgap comparing changeKeys does not work: If we compare changeKeys returned from the `EWS` call and the `REST API`, they are the same. 
Still, sometimes the headers are not present after completing `onSend` and our configured `outbound mail rule` checking the presence of the header obviously does not trigger. This leads me to think that that setting headers using EWS is not deterministic or somehow bugged, hence the (unanswered) question to set them using REST: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552123/using-extendedproperties-in-the-outlook-rest-api-to-set-message-item-headers

Comment: still no complete answer

Comment: I can't speak to the OfficeJS stuff, only the Exchange server side of things.  The only other thing that I can think of is that when Exchange sends an email, it submits the message to transport for delivery and once submitted, it copies (not moves) the message to the SentItems folder.  However, copies should be full fidelity such that all InternetMessage headers are preserved in the copy.  Now that being said, does the *delivered* email have the header set correctly?

Comment: sorry for the late response from my side. I haven't run into this issue anymore and the only way to run into it, is to keep testing sending messages. I've been keeping a watch on that, and it did not occur anymore so far... the last thing we changed was to save the item after updating the headers using SOAP, maybe this is the fix we were looking for. will update if this occurs again, if not, consider it fixed.

Comment: We would still like to know if it is possible to do this using REST instead, so we can completely remove our dependency on the one SOAP call and remove all XML parsing / error handling code...

Comment: it appears that now, our saveAsync call after setting item headers is failing, with the following error message:
`"There was an internal format error."` screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/0pj3pWs